# Problems with postgresql COPY command with Rails on different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails app that has been working successfully for months. In a few places I call directly to the database via ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( sql_code )

With a recent need to scale, I just added a second server for data processing. I want to run the same app but connect over the network to the other database server. That is the only difference here. All other areas of the app work--it can connect to the remote database.

Where it is breaking, is where I have rails issue a psql COPY command to import a csv file.

```
   result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( @PGSQL_COPY_COMMAND )     # perform the copy command
```

This fails and says that the csv file can not be found. I have verified it is there and is readable to both the user running the rails app and the postgres user.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose it is because the COPY command gets issued against the remote server who then looks for said csv file in its directory structure and doesn't find it. Bummer. I need to find a different way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use COPY FROM STDIN to get around this... like so:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
raw  = conn.raw_connection
raw.exec("COPY tablename (col1, col2, col3) FROM STDIN")
# open up your CSV file looping through line by line and getting the line into a format suitable for pg's COPY...
raw.put_copy_data line
# once all done...
raw.put_copy_end
while res = raw.get_result do; end # very important to do this after a copy
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

I believe there are some options to COPY that will let you specify you're passing in CSV data which would make it even easier...

Comment: It would be cool to mention how to consume and handle errors here, using e.g. `res.result_status` and `res.error_message`

Answer (score 16):

In pg-0.17.1 (Rails 4) there's an improved `PG::Connection::copy_data` interface to Postgres COPY.

```
  def load_file(filename)

    dbconn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
    raw  = dbconn.raw_connection
    count = nil

    result = raw.copy_data "COPY my_table FROM STDIN" do

      File.open(filename, 'r').each do |line|
        raw.put_copy_data line
      end

    end

    count = dbconn.select_value("select count(*) from #{ttable}").to_i

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(dbconn)

    count
  end
```

You can even pass an entire file buffer to put_copy_data if you aren't worried about memory usage:

```
      result = raw.copy_data "COPY my_table FROM STDIN" do
        raw.put_copy_data File.read(filename)
      end
```

Comment: If you use this and see it working in development but not in test, this is likely because tests run in a transaction and the checked out connection is therefore blind to the transaction. So, try `dbconn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection`instead

Comment: Thanks, I did not fully grok the connection_pool.checkout and you're right--it was causing me trouble in transactional tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, and execute the command with psql:

```
config = YourApp::Application.config.database_configuration[::Rails.env]
dbhost, dbuser, dbname = config['host'], config['username'], config['database']

copy_command = "\\copy theTable (col1, col2, col3) from '/a/path/to/csv' csv header;"
sql_command = "psql -U #{dbuser} -h #{dbhost} #{dbname} -c \"#{copy_command}\""

`#{sql_command}`
```