# RoR: 'rake db:seed' takes two hours

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql

I have a problem. The command 'rake db:seed' takes two hours because myfriends.txt has over 3 Miliionen entries:

```
File.open("lib/friends_name/myfriends.txt", "r").each_line do |row|
    row = row.encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1').split(',')
    Friend.create(name: row[0], first_name: row[1], age: row[2], sex: row[3], address: row[4])
end
```

Is there a quicker solution? I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Use PostgreSQL's COPY functions.  This worked at the time I wrote it up, but it's been awhile since I've used it...

[Problems with postgresql COPY command with Rails on different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779925/problems-with-postgresql-copy-command-with-rails-on-different-server/6780870#6780870)

Re-pasted code:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkout
raw  = conn.raw_connection
raw.exec("COPY tablename (col1, col2, col3) FROM STDIN")
# open up your CSV file looping through line by line and getting the line into a format suitable for pg's COPY...
rc.put_copy_data line
# once all done...
rc.put_copy_end
while res = rc.get_result do; end # very important to do this after a copy
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

Comment: At which point, the file "lib/friends_name/myfriends.txt" must be specified? Is that correct: raw.exec("COPY friends (name, first_name, age, sex, address) FROM 'lib/friends_name/myfriends.txt'") rc.put_copy_data line.encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1').split(',')

Comment: It depends on where the file is.  If that file is on the server and readable by the PostgreSQL server, then yes, you could do that.  Or you could continue to read it like you do and turn it into a `line` variable you can feed to psql's COPY.  I don't recall the format exactly, but it's in the docs.  Link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I'm curious about this line of code: "while res = rc.get_result do; end" and its corresponding "very important" comment. Could you clarify the purpose of that line, and ramifications of omitting it? I'm new to Ruby & PG, and I'm trying to avoid copying & pasting something I don't fully understand.

Comment: @MothOnMars It's been awhile since I used this, but my memory is that PG sends a series of responses after you're done copying and if you don't "fetch" them, the database connection gets out of sync and annoyed.  I wish I could remember the exact details, but that's the gist of it.