# using COPY FROM in a Rails app on Heroku with the Postgresql backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I want to give users the option of uploading files in my Ruby on Rails 3.2 application, with the data going into the db. I wanted to use the `COPY FROM` command since it is faster than inserting ruby objects.

If I do

```
User.connection.execute("COPY users (name, taxon_id, created_at, updated_at) FROM 'a.txt'")
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

However, `\copy` does not work in a db connection either. How do you easily upload data from flat files in Rails with PostgreSQL on Heroku? Can you get superuser permissions?

Comment: Use STDIN to read it...  see 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779925/problems-with-postgresql-copy-command-with-rails-on-different-server/6780870#6780870

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @PhilipHallstrom's link, I used `COPY FROM STDIN` like this:

```
rc = User.connection.raw_connection
rc.exec("COPY users (name, taxon_id, updated_at, created_at) FROM STDIN")
begin
  until rc.put_copy_data( data )
    $stderr.puts "  waiting for connection to be writable..."
    sleep 0.1
  end
rescue Errno => err
  @errmsg = @errmsg + "%s while reading copy data: %s" % [ err.class.name, err.message ]
  error = true
else
  rc.put_copy_end
  while res = rc.get_result
    if (res.result_status != 1)
      error = true
      @errmsg = @errmsg + "Result of COPY is: %s" % [ res.res_status(res.result_status) ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where does "data" come from? What format must it be in? Is it an array? String? Is there a loop somewhere where the data is being read?

Comment: Get a better idea from where data variable comes from in here: http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2013/12/15/copy-millions-of-rows-to-postgresql-with-rails/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem https://github.com/diogob/postgres-copy
Assuming `data` is an IO object.

```
User.copy_from data, columns: [:name, :taxon_id, :updated_at, :created_at]
```

Or using the path to the uploaded file directly:

```
User.copy_from "/tmp/uploaded_file.csv", columns: [:name, :taxon_id, :updated_at, :created_at]
```