# Deploying to Heroku "ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-migration

I'm having an issue migrating my application's database after it has been pushed to Heroku. The part of the code that triggers the error is the following:

```
execute "COPY countries FROM '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
execute "COPY regions FROM '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Regions.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
execute "COPY cities FROM '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Cities.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
: COPY countries FROM '/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

So far, I have attempted to use "\copy" and "COPY FROM STDIN" as some of the old questions advised but keep getting syntax errors. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

**EDIT**: Here are the questions I'm referencing. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526489/using-copy-from-in-a-rails-app-on-heroku-with-the-postgresql-backend):

I tried this:

```
execute "COPY countries FROM STDIN '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

and this:

```
execute "COPY countries FROM '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

[Two](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/67a412e40709281309t3d522e85y4570a5b7f7008eaf@mail.gmail.com):

I tried this:

```
execute \copy countries FROM STDIN '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

**Edit two**:

Here was another attempt:

```
execute "COPY countries '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
execute "COPY regions '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Regions.txt' FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
execute "COPY cities '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Cities.txt' FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

The error I got from this was:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt'"
LINE 1: COPY countries '/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt' FROM STDIN DE...
                       ^
: COPY countries '/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt' FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt'"
LINE 1: COPY countries '/app/db/migrate/Countries.txt' FROM STDIN DE...

Edit 3:

I wasn't able to resolve the issue I was having but found a simpler solution--creating a local dump and uploading that to heroku using their importing tools. Which can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).

Comment: Show us these other questions/answers you reference and the EXACT code that you're using from them please.

Comment: Ok updated my question with the alternate methods I tried.

Answer (score 14):

Realizing that the question is fairly old, I'll provide another answer for the benefit of future generations since it is the first query that shows up on Google. One easy solution I found is:

- grant the user SUPERUSER powers temporarily.

(Note that SUPERUSER is PostgreSQL flag and does not mean that you need to become system root user). You need to run the following in `psql` under `postgres` user:

```
alter user <username> superuser
```

If you do so you would not need to fight with `\copy` or `STDIN` imports anymore. This is a very quick and efficient shortcut (albeit a bit dangerous).

You can revoke the superuser privilege after you are done importing by doing:

```
alter user <username> nosuperuser
```

This solution is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004860/how-to-allow-permission-to-access-csv-file-using-postgres-in-ubuntu/29004953#29004953) answer.

Comment: `must be superuser to alter superusers`. What do I do now?

Comment: You must have entered psql as a superuser: `sudo -u postgres psql`

Comment: @DavidKuhta how do you `sudo -u postgres psql` into heroku? From what I understand and checked, there is no `postgres` user in heroku postgres

Answer (score 5):

Going through stdin worked for me... 
(admittedly, from command line. Odd escaping of Contents is Windows-ish)

```
cat import.csv | psql -c "COPY cms.\"Contents\" FROM stdin DELIMITER ',' ...
```

Answer (score 4):

according [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions) the users they create for postgres databases are created without superuser privileges. which means you don't have copy privileges.

It looks like the recommended way to import data into a heroku database is to create a db dump and import that instead of using `COPY` and csv files. Take a look at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as the error says: you are not a super user and you can't copy from a file.

Your syntax errors are the result of you using, again as the error says, invalid syntax. You can't copy from a file on Heroku, so you're going to have to make do with some other solution.

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780870/15245) is what I would recommend doing.

Comment: I attempted that answer but continue to get syntax errors (please see my updated post).

Comment: `execute "COPY countries '#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt' FROM STDIN` This is just flat-out wrong. Remove the `'#{Rails.root}/db/migrate/Countries.txt'` part. That will never work. This `COPY` command will never, ever read from a file. Please just follow that answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused on how the FROM STDIN works. I've updated my code to be as follows but still get an error (UnableToSend: another command is already in progress): 
execute `"COPY countries FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
    execute "COPY regions FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
    execute "COPY cities FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"`

Answer (score 0):

Having just wrestled with this for a django app, I thought I'd share my solution.

1. Create Staging Schema in your db
2. Create table for source data in staging
3. Import data
4. Run INSERT script to write from staging table to target table

NB: I have the staging schema to run loads and transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Via documentation:

> COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to access.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

You can overcome with next steps:

1. start psql

`sudo -u postgres psql`

2. Make user as superuser

`alter user [user] superuser;`

3. Check if user is superuser

`select usesuper from pg_user where usename = '[user]';`

P.S. Don't forget about `;`