# How to allow permission to access CSV file using postgres in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am using the following command :

```
copy (select so.name,
      so.date_order,
      sol.name,
      sol.product_Id,
      sol.product_uom_qty , 
      ai.number, 
      ai.date_invoice , 
      so.amount_total , 
      so.amount_tax 
      from sale_order so , 
      sale_order_line sol , 
      account_invoice ai 
      where so.id = sol.order_id 
      and so.name = ai.origin 
      and ai.state='open') 

to '/home/ekodev/Documents/test1.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

However, it gives the following error :

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
SQL state: 42501
Hint: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

Even when I changed the permission `ekodev@partner:~/Documents$ sudo chmod a+rwX /home/ekodev/ /home/ekodev/Documents/ /home/ekodev/Documents/test1.csv`

It still does not work for me.

Does anybody  know what the problem is?

Comment: `\copy (select .. FROM table) to '/home/ekodev/Documents/test1.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`

Comment: It is a filesystem permission thing. Easiest way to get around it is to copy to/from the `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: @unique_id  where i write this command      \copy (select .. FROM table) to '/home/ekodev/Documents/test1.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;  it also give error . and i never used psql

Comment: @Shubhambatra via psql command line utility

Comment: @Shubhambatra btw, How you're accessing postgres database?

Comment: @unique_id i am using remote desktop connection

Answer (score 57):

This solution worked for me using `\copy`. ALTER did not as that also required admin privileges.

```
psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <dbname> -c "\copy <table_name> FROM '<path to csvfile/file.csv>' with (format csv,header true, delimiter ',');"
```

Comment: I tried this way but get: ERROR:  permission denied for relation categories

Comment: I get the error identifier after -c  being truncated to 63 characters. Is there any way to make identifier longer than 63 characters?

Answer (score 30):

Out of documentation:

> COPY naming a file is only allowed to database superusers, since it
>   allows reading or writing any file that the server has privileges to
>   access.

That means, your database user needs to have the superuser flag. you can set the flag with

```
ALTER ROLE <rolename> WITH SUPERUSER
```

As this can be quiet dangerous did you consider using \copy from psql instead to copy data from client side.

Comment: Thanks! `alter user <username> superuser`  works as well. Note that, unlike `copy`, `\copy` is a psql meta-command and is not available if you are using, say, RPostgreSQL to connect to DB from R. However, your solution works from RPostgreSQL.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could use pgAdmin to import csv data. Works when the SuperUser role is not available like in for example AWS.

Comment: If you can [1] find out where it's installed (the debian package installs to /usr), and where the configuration files are (????), so that you can launch it without it furiously attempting to connect to localhost. Seriously.

Answer (score 7):

It's worked for my case

```
sudo psql -h localhost -U root -d my_db -p 5432  -c "\COPY source_table TO  '/home/user/source_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

Answer (score 6):

#### From inside database using postgres user:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

#### change file's permissions (all users can read and write):

```
chmod o+rw /tmp/amit.csv
```

#### get data from specific table:

```
\COPY table TO '/tmp/amit.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Adding the \ in front of COPY worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
GRANT pg_read_server_files TO <your user>;
```

It is not necessary to grant superuser privileges as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

The role that is running the query needs to be `SUPERUSER` to `COPY FROM` file.
Otherwise you can copy only from `STDIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Login as superuser:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Connect to your database:

```
psql database
```

Grant access to your user:

```
postgres=# grant pg_read_server_files to user;
```

After this in another tab when you connect to database as your user:

```
psql database
```

you should see:

```
database=> \du
                                          List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         |       Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------
 user      | Create DB                                                  | {pg_read_server_files}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

This means `user` can use `copy` in sql. I did a couple of test with csv, and In my tests I could only make it use full path:

```
copy table_name from '/full/path/to/your/csv/file.csv' with (format csv);
```